# How does pip detect URL of archive if version of package is not provided?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

When you run `pip install somepackage`, pip downloads the latest version of `somepackage`.

All archives on PYPI have names like `somepackage-X.X.tar.gz`. How does pip know what `X`s are? I.e. how does it detect the URL of the archive to download?

Answer (score 0):

I believe PIP relies on the containing directory being readable/listable. It then uses that directory listing to know all versions of the package, it's then easy to work out what the latest version is.

For example: https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/